# Como corrigir esse código em Java?

Tags: java

Boa noite, um professor enviou para turma uns exercícios em Java para fazer, mas como estamos no início da matéria e eu não tive nenhuma base antes, estou tendo dificuldade em resolve-lo. Alguém poderia me guiar?

O código é esse:

```
public class MathUtils {
    public static double average(int a, int b) {
        return a + b / 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(average(2,1));
    }
}
```

Ele pede para corrigi-lo de forma que dê certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é matemático. `a + b / 2` está dividindo `b` por 2 e só depois somando com `a`.

Simplesmente adicione parênteses à soma `a + b`:

```java
public static double average(int a, int b) {
    return (a + b) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, mas eu não entendi essa estrutura de programa. Poderia me explicar linha por linha? 

No caso eu pensaria em apagar tudo e fazer assim:

public class MathUtils {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int a, b;
avarege = (a+b)/2;
System.out.println(avarege);
}
}

Comment: Sim, está totalmente correto escrever assim. Porém, com a função `average()`, você não precisa se preocupar, por exemplo, em criar variáveis (ex: `a`, `b`) **toda vez** que você quiser fazer uma média de dois valores. Se o objetivo desse programa é somente fazer a média entre 2 e 1, eu diria que sua ideia é mais simples e direta. Porém, quando você estiver criando um programa maior, e precisar calcular várias médias, em várias partes do código, é bom ter funções como essas, que *podem ser usadas várias vezes sem precisarem serem reescritas todas vezes*.

Comment: Muito obrigado ;)